# SQL Server Management Studio tagging is a bit of a mess: Tag [ssms-2018] should probably be [ssms-18] (and similar for [ssms-2017]/[ssms-2016]..)

Tags: discussion, tags

As far as I know MS dropped the year flavored numbering for SSMS when it was no longer bundled with SQL Server. SQL Server had a 2016 version, but SSMS broke away into being just v16. I think a lot of people carried on calling it SSMS 2016 because of the coincident numbering with SQLS, but increasingly (and especially with v17) people started talking about it in terms of minor versions like v17.2 which helped split it away from year numbering. Calling it SSMS 2017 sort of lingered on a little because of the 2017 / v17 coincidence

I see we have a tag [ssms-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2018) but to my knowledge there has never been any SSMS related to 2018 - it's SSMS v18 and is related to SQL Server 2019, but it doesn't carry the year as a version indicator. I think this [ssms-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2018) tag was probably created in error by confusion with v18 (which was released in 2019, btw)

I think [ssms-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2018) tags on questions should be replaced with [ssms-18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-18) and the [ssms-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2018) tag should be deleted. A similar thing should happen for [ssms-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2017). It would perhaps make sense to make [ssms-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2016) and [ssms-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-16) synonymous because it was the transitional point in people's minds (even though the actual transition was 2014->16) but I'm unsure whether [ssms-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2017) should be a synonym of [ssms-17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-17) or whether [ssms-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2017) should be flagged as "use [ssms-17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms-17) instead"..

Any thoughts?

Comment: People, often seem to refer to SSMS 18 as "SSMS 2018", but they also have a habit of talking about things like "SQL Server 2013" when they mean Version 13 of SQL Server, which is SQL server 2016. People just don't seem to read about what the application actually says, and *assume* version means year. I completely agree that things like [[tag:ssms-2018]] should be correctly retagged and the old one burninated.

Comment: If it's commonly misunderstood, would synonyms be helpful in this case? (Synonymize year tags to version tags)

Comment: My concern would be that synonymizing them all would reinforce something that isn't true. We shouldn't have tags for things that don't exist, and especailly things that aren't even accidentally relatable (you'd be creating `productnamehere-yearofrelease -> productnamehere-version` all over the place for MS.. and what when a product has a major update mid way through a year?) All in, i think we've enough isssues managing tags for things that do exist without creating more for things that don't/wouldn't if people just operated with a modicum of precision/looked in help-about before they post...

Comment: ..but equally I appreciate that trying to effect that change is like telling the sea to go back :D

Comment: Never mind the fact that most posts tagged [tag:ssms] (and friends) are not actually about SSMS but about SQL Server, and poster just doesn't understand the difference

Comment: Radical solution: just have the ssms tag. Seems that askers wouldn't use them correctly anyways, and so we would only have 1 tag to fix.

Comment: There is simply no collation between the version of SQL Server and Management Studio anymore.

Comment: I'm with @Braiam here. I've yet to see any ssms tag be actually useful, let alone a specific version of ssms.

Comment: I've seen it a few times, @DavidG , though mainly it was specifically about SSMS 18, as there were a few deprecations and changes in the release; so the OP tagging [[tag:ssms-18]] (or incorrectly [[tag:ssms-2018]]) was useful in such cases.

Comment: @Larnu but it was useful how?

Comment: What was useful how, @Braiam , the tag? Because before I had even opened the question, I knew from the title and tags that the reason the OP was asking the question was because the problem was specific to SSMS 18.

Comment: @Larnu That's not the way tags are meant to be useful. You aren't supposed to summarize the problem using tags, for that there's the title. Also, as noted above: most of the time, that information is wrong or irrelevant.

Comment: What...? Tags are exactly there to help know what the question is about @Braiam ... It's you who seems to misunderstandong their use, not me. If the question is specially about SSMS 18 then tagging [[tag:ssms-18]] is ***useful***. With respect, I'm not sure what's hard to understand about that.

Comment: @Braiam have you got something authoritative that says we aren't supposed to use tags to indicate a query is about a specific version of anything? Version based tagging is pervasive

Comment: @Larnu "Tags are exactly there to help know what the question is about" [citation-needed] ["Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories. "](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Why people don't understand the purpose of tags. They are there for the answerers. They aren't meant to be a librarians dream of tagging works of art with #hastags. (cc Caius)

Comment: I'm an answerer, @Braiam, if you weren't aware. Again, the tag told me the version the OP was using, the title told me the problem, I knew I could answer the question. Bingo bango, the tags (in this case [[tag:ssms-18]]) have done their job... If you don't like that, I am sorry you feel that way.

Comment: Does that wiki page say anywhere that version specific tags shouldn't be used? If anything my take away from it is that tags should be usably specific and are not supposed to be crammed into titles. [mysql] is not usably specific; MySQL 8 added a plethora of useful features that were sorely lacking from 5.x. Tagging a question with [mysql] would not, on its own, inform the answerer as to whether they could use ROW_NUMBER OVER, for example. As an answerer, I would prefer to focus on mysql 8 questions because I can't be bothered with the limited facilities of 5.7. The [mysql-8.0] suits me well

Comment: To further add to @CaiusJard point, I personally tend to avoid questions tagged with versions of SQL Server that are completely unsupported, as I have no way to test the behaviours on such versions, and I honestly can't remember what isn't supported on a version that was released 13+ years ago and hasn't been supported for 2+ years. Like wise, for a period of time I used to sometimes ignore those tagged with [[tag:sql-server-2017]]+ when the question appeared to use 2017+ features, as I didn't have use to have access to a 2017+ instance there (I do now).

Comment: We are overly pedantic about tags.  A single [ssms] tag really ought to suffice.  If the version is important, it can go into the body of the post.  I really doubt that people follow these version-specific tags unless they have to (because people tag their posts with them instead of using the main tag).

Comment: It looks like this was at least implemented for [[tag:ssms-2018]] and [[tag:ssms-18]] (the prior returns no posts now). [[tag:ssms-2017]], is however, far more prevalent than [[tag:ssms-17]], despite the latter being the correct tag. There are "only" 170 questions, so I'm "happy" (read content) to edit all these, but a mod making [[tag:ssms-2017]] and synonym of [[tag:ssms-17]] would be far more preferable.

Answer (score 9):

I agree, a moderator should rename these tags; they currently refer to things that simply don't exist; the versions are not years, as you mentioned. SSMS 18 didn't even get fully released until 2019 anyway.